# alert from a provider in ionic2

Tags: ionic2, ionic2-providers

> My idea is to create an alert in a provider and use it in  which ever page its needed.so I wrote this code in provider

```js
constructor(public alertCtl:AlertController) {
    
  }
presentDismissAlert(  navCtrl: NavController) {
  let alert = this.alertCtl.create({
                    title: 'connect your charger',
                    subTitle: '10% is remaining',
                    buttons: ['Dismiss']
        });
  navCtrl.present(alert);   
 }
```

> and in a page I am  calling this method as follows

```js
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public alt : alertProvider ) {
   this.altCtrl.presentDismissAlert(this.navCtrl);
        }
```

but this error remains `  Property 'present' does not exist on type 'NavController'.

```
  L22:         });
  L23:   navCtrl.present(alert);
```

`any help  regarding this

Answer (score 2):

You dont need `navController` to present alert.
Check [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/).

```
presentDismissAlert() {
        let alert = this.alertCtl.create({
                    title: 'connect your charger',
                    subTitle: '10% is remaining',
                    buttons: ['Dismiss']
        });
     alert.present()   
    }
```

Comment: glad it worked..consider accepting and closing this question :)